# Hypothesis testing on an empirical distribution

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, p-value

This may be a basic question, so please pardon me: given a vector of univariate data, and an individual observation from the said univariate data, I would like to derive some probability of observing this individual observation, or a more extreme observation, from the empirical distribution of the said univariate data (aka. the p-value).

May I ask how can this be done in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's start with $p$-value, because it seems you have a wrong understanding of $p$-values. They are *not* the "probability of observing this individual observation, or a more extreme observation, from the distribution". Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)

> $p$-value is a function of the observed sample results (a statistic)
>   that is used for testing a statistical hypothesis. Before performing
>   the test a threshold value is chosen, called the significance level of
>   the test, traditionally 5% or 1% and denoted as $\alpha$. If the
>   $p$-value is equal to or smaller than the significance level
>   ($\alpha$), it suggests that the observed data are inconsistent with
>   the assumption that the null hypothesis is true, and thus that
>   hypothesis must be rejected and the alternative hypothesis is accepted
>   as true. When the $p$-value is calculated correctly, such a test is
>   guaranteed to control the Type I error rate to be no greater than
>   $\alpha$.
>
> An equivalent interpretation is that $p$-value is the probability of
>   obtaining the observed sample results, or "more extreme" results, when
>   the null hypothesis is actually true (where "more extreme" is
>   dependent on the way the hypothesis is tested).

for learning more on $p$-values check [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests).

As about checking what is the probability of observing a certain value $x$ in your [empirical distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) (i.e. data) - for this you simply count how many times $x$ occurred in your data.

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,2,1,4,3,1,2,6,7,8,8,1,2)
x <- 5
mean(data == x) # P(data = x)
mean(data >= x) # P(data >= x)
```

however, let me say it again, this is *not* a $p$-value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. I see now where my confusion with p-values lie now, thanks for your clarification, and the solution you provided to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to interpret your computation as a p-value if you want to 'test' whether the individual observation is from the same distribution as the available data. One could then consider the data as a bootstrap sample from the distribution. Your null hypothesis would be H_0: x ~ f_0, where x is the individual observation. Then your calculation could be looked at a bootstrap test, and your computation the p-value, because you are treating x as the 'test statistic' and you computation is being done under the null hypothesis.

On the other hand, the way you have written your question, you've just calculated the Prob. of a certain area, as the above answer points out.

Comment: (1) To what "computation" are you referring?  The question doesn't seem to describe one.  (2) How would a "bootstrap" sample of a distribution differ from a sample of the distribution?  (3) What is "f_0" in your null hypothesis?  Remember, a null must refer to the *underlying distribution,* not to the data.